# How to stream multiple logs from docker container using log driver

Tags: logging, docker, amazon-cloudwatch

If I have one log in a docker container, and I only can choose 1 log to stream to stdout, it works great. But what if I have multiple logs in a docker container and I want to use a aws log driver to stream each log to cloudwatch?

For example I have tomcat application log, tomcat access log, and tomcat error log.

Ideally I would want each log to stream to it's own log group. So it would be something like this:

```
O AWS_cloudwatch_log_group_application_logs
  - log_stream_application_logs_instance_a
  - log_stream_application_logs_instance_b
  - log_stream_application_logs_instance_c
O AWS_cloudwatch_log_group_access_logs
  - log_stream_access_logs_instance_a
  - log_stream_access_logs_instance_b
  - log_stream_access_logs_instance_c
O AWS_cloudwatch_log_group_error_logs
  - log_stream_error_logs_instance_a
  - log_stream_error_logs_instance_b
  - log_stream_error_logs_instance_c
O AWS_cloudwatch_log_group_catalina_logs
  - log_stream_catalina_logs_instance_a
  - log_stream_catalina_logs_instance_b
  - log_stream_catalina_logs_instance_c
```

How would I acheive this?

Comment: The only way I can think of is with mapping volumes to the host, and installing a cloud-watch log agent on the host and streaming the logs this way, but that is too messy, looking for a better solution (if one exists)

Comment: I have my logs mapped to the host, just as you described. It works fine, but it is kinda messy. I don't know of any better way to do it.